# Is there a way to search by a column added after a left join using Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have the models `Item` and `User`. The model `Item` has the attribute `name`, but I want to have a custom name by a user so I have created an intermediate table and its respective model `ItemsUser` with its own `name`.

Now, I'm trying to include this attribute in a table where I show all the items of the logged user. In this table, I use Ransack to order and find records by some column values.

In order to find I have tried using: `:name_or_items_users_name_cont` or order with `sort_link(@q, :items_users_name, 'Custom Name')` but I need to make a custom join to filter by a user so I cannot use these solutions.

I have got in the controller:

```rb
@q = user.items
  .joins("LEFT JOIN items_users ON items_users.item_id = items.id AND items_users.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
  .select('items.*, items_users.name AS custom_name')
  .ransack(params[:q])
```

It works ok when I check the `custom_name` of a record (for example `@q.result.first.custom_name`).

In the view, I have the code below to order, but checking the SQL generated by the ransack method, I can't see the order clause:

```rb
= sort_link(@q, :custom_name, 'Custom name')
```

and the code below to find:

```rb
= search_form_for @q, url: manager_items_path do |f|
  = f.search_field :name_or_custom_name_cont
  = f.button :submit
```

but I get the error below when I render the view:

```
undefined method `name_or_custom_name_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: Item, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

I don't know if I can achieve my objective using Ransack or I have to create my custom search system or use another one.